# Two ways to create a ring graph

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Suppose we have graph with a following properties:

- Nodes are arranged in a circle
- Each node is connected to its **k** next neighbors

I have two functions to greate a graph:

```
def ring_graph1(n, k):
   graph = nx.Graph()

   sources = np.arange(n)
   for i in range(1, k + 1):
       targets = np.roll(sources, i)
       graph.add_edges_from(zip(sources, targets))

   return graph

def ring_graph2(n, k):
   graph = nx.Graph()

   for i in range(n):
      sources = [i] * k
      targets = range(i + 1, i + k + 1)
      targets = [node % n for node in targets]
      graph.add_edges_from(zip(sources, targets))

   return graph
```

Naively I would expect that the first would work faster, because it is dealing with `np.array` and at one time allocates less memory, and because **k < n** it allocates less memory.

But measurements have shown, that:

```
times1 = []
times2 = []

for k in [2, 10, 50, 100, 200, 500]:
   t = %timeit -o ring_graph1(1000, k)
   times1.append(t.average)
   t = %timeit -o ring_graph2(1000, k)
   times2.append(t.average)
```

The second way performs approximately 1.5 times faster. Why it can be the case?[image]

Comment: `np.roll()` returns a new array, so it too allocates on every invocation.

Comment: Are you checking for execution time or more memory allocation? IMO they are 2 different parameters of performance, unless machine is low on resources

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like the first implementation adds the same edge multiple times, which is suppressed by `networkx`. That is, `zip(sources, targets)` always has size `n`, in the first version and size `k` in the second.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I've read, that adding the same edge multiple times has no effect, but makes uneccesary actions, I thought initially the the graph is directed by default

Comment: If you change the functions to not use Networkx (for now) and just return a set of edge 2-tuples, the two functions don't have the same return value. To have them be equal, use `np.roll(sources, -i)` (flip the roll direction).

Comment: I would add that the builtin `nx.circulant_graph(1000, range(1, 501))` produces the same graph as `ring_graph2(1000, 500)` but is actually slower than your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth,

```
def ring_graph3(n, k):
    edges = set()
    node_ids = list(range(n)) * 2

    for i in range(n):
        sources = [i] * k
        targets = node_ids[i + 1 : i + k + 1]
        edges.update(set(zip(sources, targets)))

    return edges
```

where you don't have to do the modulus pass is even faster (n=1000, k=500):

```
ring_graph1: 2.64 ops/s (1 loops in 0.379351074)
ring_graph2: 5.29 ops/s (2 loops in 0.378035934)
ring_graph3: 5.75 ops/s (2 loops in 0.34760668299999997)
```

### Numpy magic edit!

After a bit of work, this returns the same set of edge pairs much, much faster:

```
def ring_graph5(n, k):
    nxk = np.arange(0, n).repeat(k)
    src = nxk.reshape(n, k)
    dst = np.mod(np.tile(np.arange(0, k), n) + (nxk + 1), n).reshape((n, k))
    flat_pairs = np.dstack((src, dst)).flatten().tolist()
    return zip(flat_pairs[::2], flat_pairs[1::2])
```

```
ring_graph1: 2.92 ops/s (1 loops in 0.3422120950000007)
ring_graph2: 5.77 ops/s (2 loops in 0.34680103699999876)
ring_graph3: 6.93 ops/s (2 loops in 0.28863287499999934)
ring_graph4: 6.03 ops/s (2 loops in 0.3317746049999979)
ring_graph5: 19.43 ops/s (5 loops in 0.25736287700000204)
```

Comment: When I include the graph creation and a call to `add_edges_from` in your latest benchmark, it seems to be slower than OP's `ring_graph2` for `n=1000` and `k=500`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Well, I added one more implementation that's just raw numpy magic :)

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator You too may be interested in the new implementation

Comment: @AKX that is  a creative numpy solution. My take is that edge generation is not really a limiting factor in this problem, at least for large values of `k`. I posted an answer to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the bottleneck is the builtin `add_edges_from` rather than edge generation. Maybe this is to be expected, as `networkx` is designed to handle more complex cases, such as edge attributes. In fact, there is a builtin method that allows you to construct ring graphs, e.g.

```
nx.circulant_graph(1000, range(1, 501))
```

is equivalent to

```
ring_graph2(1000, 500)
```

but the builtin version is actually *slower* than your version.

Getting back to edge generation, consider the following implementation:

```
def get_edges(n, k):
  modmap = np.tile(np.arange(n), 2)
  a, b = np.meshgrid(range(n), range(k))
  return zip(a.T.ravel().tolist(), modmap[(a+b+1).T.ravel()].tolist())


assert set(get_edges(1000, 500)) == set(ring_graph5(1000, 500))

%timeit get_edges(1000, 500)   # 10 loops, best of 3: 32 ms per loop
%timeit ring_graph5(1000, 500) # 10 loops, best of 3: 61 ms per loop


def graph_from_edge_generator(f, n, k):
  g = nx.Graph()
  g.add_edges_from(f(n, k))
  return g

%timeit graph_from_edge_generator(get_edges, 1000, 500)   # 1 loop, best of 3: 772 ms per loop
%timeit graph_from_edge_generator(ring_graph5, 1000, 500) # 1 loop, best of 3: 783 ms per loop
```

In both cases, edge generation takes less than 10% percent of the runtime.